# Add new row in the end of my table copying the previous format and increment the number of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a new row to my excel sheet and copy the previous format, also I have ID column what I would like to keep increment the number +1.

I am using this code

```
Sub Addrisk()

'add new rows below-above
Dim rActive As Range

Set rActive = ActiveCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    .EntireRow.Copy
    With .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
        On Error Resume Next
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End With

rActive.Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your table an actual table object? (`ListObject`)?

Comment: my table is a list of items

Comment: If you make it an actual table (Ctrl + T), adding and modifying new rows becomes much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your formatting you probably need to remove the statement "pasteformulas" from within your with block

```
With .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
       On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

If you want to format after you paste formulas then you use the CellFormat Object to then format your row as you would like it.

Comment: Pasting a formula may not necessarily capture the formatting, whereas pasting formulas would.  Is this pasting two rows?  One would be formatted and the other wouldn't be.

Comment: When I just paste formats, some of the formatting comes across.  You could use the CellFormat object to have it come back and format the cells in the explicit way you want it.